# Change language intro slider

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an option so that when the user first enters the app they get a language selection menu, however for some reason it's not working

Here is my intro_slide_language_selection.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/glavna"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <!-- Naslov -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Izaberite jezik"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <!-- Zastave sa dugmadima -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <!-- Srpska zastava i dugme -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/srpski"
                android:contentDescription="Zastava Srpske" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSerbian"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Srpski"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Ruska zastava i dugme -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ruski"
                android:contentDescription="Ruska zastava" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnRussian"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ruski"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Mađarska zastava i dugme -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/madj"
                android:contentDescription="Zastava Mađarske" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnHungarian"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mađarski"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

After that i added in my IntroSliderActivity.java

```
layouts = new int[]{
                R.layout.intro_slide_language_selection, // this is the lang selector
                R.layout.intro_slide_1,
                R.layout.intro_slide_2,
                R.layout.intro_slide_3,
                R.layout.intro_slide_4,
        };
```

then i added

```
 // Dohvatite dugmad za izbor jezika
        View languageSelectionLayout = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.intro_slide_language_selection, null);
        Button btnSerbian = languageSelectionLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnSerbian);
        Button btnRussian = languageSelectionLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnRussian);
        Button btnHungarian = languageSelectionLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnHungarian);

// Postavite OnClickListener za svako dugme
        btnSerbian.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Postavite jezik na srpski
                LocaleHelper.setAppLocale0(getApplicationContext(), "en");
                // Restartujte aktivnost kako biste primenili promenu jezika
                restartActivity();
            }
        });

        btnRussian.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Postavite jezik na ruski
                LocaleHelper.setAppLocale0(getApplicationContext(), "ru");
                // Restartujte aktivnost kako biste primenili promenu jezika
                restartActivity();
            }
        });

        btnHungarian.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Postavite jezik na mađarski
                LocaleHelper.setAppLocale0(getApplicationContext(), "hu");
                // Restartujte aktivnost kako biste primenili promenu jezika
                restartActivity();
            }
        });
```

And i made restartactivity

```
    private void restartActivity() {
        // Restartujte trenutnu aktivnost
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

This is a part of the setup that works without problems it might be useful ( this is form another its from settings )

```
    private void setupLanguageSelector() {

        ListPreference changeLanguage = (ListPreference) findPreference("changeLanguage");
        changeLanguage.setEnabled(true);
        changeLanguage.setShouldDisableView(true);

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String defaultLanguageCode = sharedPref.getString("changeLanguage", "en");
        String defaultLanguageTitle = sharedPref.getString("changeLanguage", "English");

        String storedLanguages = "en:English,ru:Russian,es:Spanish,hr:Hrvatski";
        CharSequence[] splinted = storedLanguages.split(",");
        CharSequence[] languageEntries = new CharSequence[splinted.length];
        CharSequence[] languageEntryValues = new CharSequence[splinted.length];

        int i = 0;
        for (CharSequence item : storedLanguages.split(",")) {

            CharSequence[] language = item.toString().split(":");
            languageEntries[i] = language[1] + " (" + language[0] + ")";
            languageEntryValues[i] = language[0];

            if (defaultLanguageCode.equals(language[0])) {
                defaultLanguageTitle = language[1].toString();
            }

            i++;
        }

        changeLanguage.setEntries(languageEntries);
        changeLanguage.setEntryValues(languageEntryValues);
        changeLanguage.setSummary(defaultLanguageTitle);


        changeLanguage.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                //Change language setting
                LocaleHelper.setAppLocale0(getApplicationContext(), newValue.toString());
                //It is required to recreate the activity to reflect the change in UI.
                AlertBottomSheetDialog mAlertBottomSheetDialog = AlertBottomSheetDialog.newInstance(SettingActivity.this);
                mAlertBottomSheetDialog.setlisteners(new AlertBottomSheetDialog.Listeners() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConfirm() {
                        finishAffinity();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss() {

                    }
                });

                mAlertBottomSheetDialog.titleView().setText(getString(R.string.change_language));
                mAlertBottomSheetDialog.bodyView().setText(getString(R.string.to_apply_languageMessage));
                mAlertBottomSheetDialog.show();
                return true;
            }
        }

        );

    }
```

I tried everything I knew :D

Comment: Which part of your code not working?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).